# rkhunter: whitlist for test 'packet_cap_apps'

Tags: linux, rkhunter

W have here a CentOS 7 server with rkhunter installed. Since yesterday we get following rkhunter warning:

```
[01:10:30] Info: Starting test name 'packet_cap_apps'
[01:10:30]   Checking for packet capturing applications      [ Warning ]
[01:10:30] Warning: Process '/usr/sbin/NetworkManager' (PID 4654) is listening on the network.
```

Is there a way to whitelist `/usr/sbin/NetworkManager` for the `packet_cap_apps` test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `rkhunter.conf` there is an option to disable tests on certain apps with the `DISABLE_TESTS` parameter where you can add the apps that you don't want to be tested as space separated value. Alternatively you can use `SCRIPTWHITELIST` option to whitelist `/usr/sbin/NetworkManager` in case you want to still run tests on `packet_cap_apps`.

Comment: `SCRIPTWHITELIST` is what I want! :-) I know `SCRIPTWHITELIST`but don't know that I can also use that for the `packet_cap_apps` check. Thx.

Comment: rkhunter documentation is not the best ;-) I was in your shoes when I first started using it. Glad it works.

Comment: After some days the error is still back. Not sure why. Error is: `Warning: Process '/usr/sbin/NetworkManager' (PID 4656) is listening on the network`. `NetworkManager` is whitelisted with: `SCRIPTWHITELIST=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager`. However, I have disable the test now by adding `packet_cap_apps` to `DISABLE_TESTS`

Comment: One way to test would be to kill the process. In case this happens again then try to run a manual test with verbosity and check the logs, this might lead you to the cause.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the `ALLOWPROCLISTEN` directive instead of `SCRIPTWHITELIST`:

```
ALLOWPROCLISTEN=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager
```

Regards,

Michael